# '-[__NSCFString setLocationPingTimer:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

This is showing up.

I'm using CoreLocation.

Googling for setLocationPingTimer doesn't show anything.

Comment: It seems `setLocationPingTimer:` is sent to an `NSString` object which doesn't implement this method, thus causing the crash.

Comment: Could you add code snippet please

Comment: Google-ing for [locationPingTimer](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=locationPingTimer&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN534IN534&oq=locationPingTimer&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.5250j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) indicates that you are using [open source code](https://github.com/perspecdev/PSLocationManager). Post your code or raise a bug with the [project author](http://www.perspecdev.com/blog/2012/02/22/using-corelocation-on-ios-to-track-a-users-distance-and-speed/).

Comment: I'm retarded, I searched for setLocationPingTimer not locationPingTimer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending the `setLocationPingTimer:` message to an `NSString` object. Mostly likely, the object that *should* accept the message has been deallocated and a string happens to be in the same memory location. That's to say, you really have a memory management issue.